# Marshalling on P/Invoke: Shouldn't I see it in the disassembler?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Consider this snippet:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern char CharLower([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] string lpsz);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = CharLower("A");

    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

(Note that this isn't the correct signature of the real `CharLower` function, but that's not the point here.)

When I disassemble this with the VS debugger, I get

```
            var a = CharLower("A");
00AB34DA  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[340230Ch]  
00AB34E0  call        00AB0C34  
00AB34E5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  
00AB34E8  movzx       eax,word ptr [ebp-44h]  
00AB34EC  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax
```

When I then change the signature to `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]`, I get something similar:

```
            var a = CharLower("A");
00DE34DA  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[37C230Ch]  
00DE34E0  call        00DE0C34  
00DE34E5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  
00DE34E8  movzx       eax,word ptr [ebp-44h]  
00DE34EC  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax
```

The only difference seem to be the memory locations.

Shouldn't the marshalling code be visible here? Isn't the function that gets called what was defined as `CharLower` in `user32.dll`?

Comment: The marshalling will happen further down the call stack.

Comment: Can I step into that machine-code wise? The debugger controls in VS seem to step over C# statements only.

Comment: I'm sure that would be possible, but it's not something I've ever done. Why are you asking the question in the first place?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't actually have a concrete problem, I simply want to have a better understanding about the glue between C# and C to satisfy my curiosity. In particular regarding how direct a call to C from C# really can be and how much translation/marshalling is required.

Comment: The attribute is something that the *field marshaller* inside the CLR deals with.  Very convoluted code, it is massively micro-optimized, your eyes will bleed in 10 seconds flat.

Comment: Did you *try* stepping into the code? What happened? Note that to do this you will need to enable mixed-mode debugging, which has its own set of problems... If you're just curious about the internals of the implementation, you might have better luck reading the code for the open-source [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr).

Comment: @CodyGray or more specifically, [this file](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/fieldmarshaler.cpp) in the CoreCLR.